# In a new window with a blank URL, how can you provide a path from which to find relative resources?

Tags: javascript, robotframework, relative-path, popupwindow

This question started with a Robot Framework test against a public website with lots of functionality. As part of the data generated by the test, I wanted to capture screenshots. The whole report is formatted as HTML with JavaScript data sources. So RF puts data into the .JS file and the HTML reads it.

I was having problems with the images. They didn't show up up in the popup window report and I couldn't figure out why.
[image]

The paths exported from RF were relative and they worked perfectly well from the main page of the report, but not in the popup.
[image]

The problem appears to be that a "blank" popup has no window.location from which to search for resources. I even ran a quick experiment to show that the whole path from the main window (left) was not accesible from the popup (right).

[image]

Thanks to a comment about absolute vice relative paths, I updated the RF code to output absolute paths. Now my code has the effect I want, but I am left with a remaining question about blank windows and paths.

[image]

I can make the images work, but I have style sheets and javascript files that I would also like to refer to. Right now I'm writing everything in line by line which seems excessive. Surely there is a way to setup a path for a new window which can be used as a starting point for relative resources.

Comment: where does that relative URL point?  to about:blank/./theAddress.png?  If you put in the solid address it shows fine.

Comment: @ChrisStrickland well that is a step in the right direction. The system where these files resides is placing everything in relative paths. I suppose I could override that and give them absolute paths. I guess my problem at this point is why isn't working with relative paths?

Comment: @ChrisStrickland I'm willing to admit defeat at this point. I have tweaked RF to output absolute paths and that seems to work. I'm going to edit the quetion to improve and focus. I'd like to give you credit for the answer if you wouldn't mind writing it up below.

Comment: I don't, but let me check one thing.

Comment: Check into the <base> element.  This will let you set the base path for the new window, I think, and then you should be able to stick with relative paths.  Here's the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base.  I assume you are writing the html to the new window with js, in which case you will want to create the base element, append it to the head, and then set base.href to what you need the base path to be.  Try that and let me know what happens.

Comment: We have a winner! That worked perfectly. Would you please add the base element as an answer rather than a comment so I can give you the credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the imgs are given relative URLs to work with (as they should be).  I am not 100% positive what the base URL is for window.open.  I don't know if it's about:blank, but since the absolute URLs work and the relative ones don't, I think it's a safe bet that the browser doesn't know where to point to.

So add a  element to explicitly tell it where to point.  Here is the documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

I assume that you are writing elements to the window with js, so in that case you will want to create the base element, append it to the head and set base.href to the base url you are using.

I think you might save yourself some trouble on things like this by NOT using window.open (which got a really bad rap in the bad days of popups) and use a hidden modal div that you can load (or write) html into, then unhide.  However, you might have a completely valid reason for using the popup.

Comment: Much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you also for the comment about popups and modals. I have a different question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70100196/more-modern-ways-to-dynamically-create-html-content/70439428#70439428) trying to find out more about the preferred modern methods for displaying dynamic content. I followed up on your comment and I think that information will be very helpful.

Comment: No problem, glad it is helpful.  There's nothing wrong with using a new window, but they got such a bad rap (and I guess malicious actors are still trying to use them for exploits) that I think popups are generally blocked now, either by default or by user setting.